# Rails test that can serve HTTP requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to have a Rails (3.2.9) test respond to HTTP GET queries from outside programs (almost as though you had run 'rails s')?

I have a RESTful Rails web service and a companion native SDK that talks to it. I want it so when I run 'rake test', one of the tests launches a little test program that uses my native SDK, and have that SDK make some GET requests to the same Rails test environment that launched it. I want the Rails test to wait for the SDK test program to exit, and report an error if the test program encountered an error.

This way, I'm testing the actual native SDK code against an actual Rails server rather than simulating the SDK's requests in my unit tests.

Is there a way to do this?